# NPM sqlite3 with sqlcipher support

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to cross compile NPM Sqlite3 with sqlcipher support. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 to cross compile for linux armv7 based SOC(system on chip).

So I started with cross-compiling OpenSSL to build sqlcipher for arm. I successfully cross compiled sqlcipher to produce a static library (libsqlcipher.a).

Now I am trying to get the NodeJS side of the project. I need sqlite with sqlcipher support, compiled for arm. I am using SOC SDK to built till now.

I am using node v4.6.1 and npm v2.15.9 to cross compile. I made sure I have the same version installed on Ubuntu as the SOC.

The command I use to cross compile is as follows :

```
npm install sqlite3 --target_arch=arm --enable-static=yes --build-from-source --sqlite_libname=sqlcipher -fPIC --sqlite=home/onkar/Library/sqlcipher-master/.libs --verbose
```

I exported the location of the libsqlcipher.a to LDFLAGS. I get the following error when I try to cross compile. Can someone help me with this error?

```
/home/linuximage/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/5.2.1/real-ld: error: /home/Library/sqlcipher-master/.libs/libsqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC; recompile with -fPIC 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
node_sqlite3.target.mk:129: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/node_sqlite3.node' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_sqlite3.node] Error 1
```

Please let me know if you require any additional information, I would be more than happy to provide you with the same.

Thanks,
Onkar

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, you should check if the -fPIC (position independent code) flag was correctly applied when the libsqlcipher.a file was originally created.

In your output above, it looks like the linker is using the file at:
/home/Library/sqlcipher-master/.libs/libsqlcipher.a

Run the command

```
objdump -r /home/Library/sqlcipher-master/.libs/libsqlcipher.a | more
```

... and check for a line close to the start of the output beginning with the text

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR
```

If you see this line, then the library doesn't contain position independent code.